# Y a-t-il une différence entre « pays tiers » et « tiers pays » ?

Tags: adjectifs, ordre-des-mots, nombres

J'aimerais inviter les avis des doctes contributeurs concernant ces deux expressions.

Dans un contexte UE ou bien Brexit, on utilise souvent l'expression "pays tiers".  En langage Communautaire cela veut dire, bien sûr, un pays qui n'est pas un membre ni de l'Union elle-même ni même de l'Espace Economique Européenne.

Pour moi, Anglophone, par contre, cette expression "pays tiers" ne veut pas dire "troisième pays", mais plutôt "pays en dehors de [quelque chose]", "pays qui est étranger [à tel groupement]". Selon moi, cet usage est en fait emprunté au langage juridique français, et signifie, dans un contexte d'un accord bilatéral, toutes les autres parties desquelles il y est fait mention, sauf les 2 contractants eux-mêmes... ce qui se traduit en anglais par l'adjectif juridique "third-party"...

Par contre, si ce genre d'adjectif ordinal français *précède* le nom, il me semble qu'il veut dire "troisième" tout simplement, sur le modèle de "prime", "second" et (jadis) "quart".  Et tous ces adjectifs ne doivent-ils pas toujours *précéder* le nom ? "Tiers Monde", "Tiers Etat", "second avis", ou même "Achevons cette quarte bouteille et tirons nos grègues d'ici" (Gautier, Fracasse).

Dans ce contexte de Brexit / UE on traduit en anglais systématiquement "pays tiers" par "Third Country". Cet usage est fait non seulement par la presse britannique mais aussi par les instances européennes.

Mais je pense qu'il s'agit d'un "faux ami" (traduction erronée tirée d'une similitude trompeuse entre deux langues) ... et j'avoue que cela m'agace !  Je pense que l'expression "Non-EU country" serait plus appropriée.  "Tiers pays" / "third country" serait, selon moi, une expression qu'on utiliserait en parlant d'un des pays dans une liste de 10 pays.

Pour un Francophone lettré (cultivé) d'un bon niveau d'éducation, comment caractériseriez-vous la différence des significations des ces deux expressions, "pays tiers" et "tiers pays" ?  Ou bien peut-être n'acceptez-vous pas qu'il existe de différence, aussi subtile soit-elle...

Comment: Avis personnel: "pays tiers" est relativement courant dans la presse, les contextes juridiqiues, etc. , mais "tiers pays" me semble à priori inusité en français "usuel", "tiers" dans le sens de "troisième" n'étant plus utilisé que dans des expressions fixes comme celles que vous citez. On dira plutôt "troisième pays". Si je lisais "tiers pays" dans un article, je pense que je pourrais le comprendre non pas comme le troisième pays d'une liste, mais que je l'interprêterais comme "élement extérieur, qui s'avère être un pays" ("tiers" étant alors utilisé comme nom).

Comment: Merci... très intéressant : il ne m'est pas venu à l'esprit que la tendance francophone dans ce cas serait de supposer que "tiers" serait le **nom** dans l'expression "tiers pays" (et "pays" une sorte d'adjectif épithète...)

Comment: Non *pays* ne peut être un adjectif. À la limite, dans des cas très pathologiques il pourrait s'agir d'une collation de deux noms, comme dans *discours fleuve* par exemple, mais généralement *tiers* serait aussi un adjectif dans « tiers pays ». Je ne m'attendrais cependant pas à trouver « tiers pays » ailleurs que dans un phrasé littéraire ou poétique.

Comment: C'est ce que j'entendais : un type d'"épithète" est justement un nom qui fonctionne en qq sorte comme un adjectif pour qualifier un autre nom, comme "discours fleuve"...

Comment: Voir [ici](https://www.eurofound.europa.eu/observatories/eurwork/industrial-relations-dictionary/third-country-nationals) l'idée de dérivé puis de généralisation (avec [_third country national_](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Third_country_national)). Dans un contexte différent de celui de l'Europe, le Canada a employé [_tiers pays sûrs_](http://www.btb.termiumplus.gc.ca/tpv2alpha/alpha-fra.html?lang=fra&i=1&srchtxt=TIERS+PAYS&index=alt&codom2nd_wet=1#resultrecs) pour _safe third country_, mais le texte d'une entente avec les É.-U. qu'on présente de cette manière contient _pays tiers sûrs_ !

Answer (score 2):

Un pays tiers est un pays différent des deux pays qui sont sujets principaux.

Par exemple dans un accord entre la France et l'Allemagne, l'Angleterre est un pays tiers. L'italie et l'Espagne aussi d'ailleurs, ce qui fait que le tiers pays pays peut aussi être un quatrième ou cinquième pays.

Quand à "tiers pays", ce n'est tout simplement pas français. J'ai bien appris à l'école que "blanc bonnet" et "bonnet blanc" étaient interchangeables, on entendra jamais une "rouge voiture" ni une "voiture grande", sans que que je puisse dire pourquoi.

Pas tout à fait, si je recontrais le "tiers pays" dans un texte d'ancien français, je comprendrais qu'on parle de la contrée qui est située plus loin que le pays voisin.

Comment: "Dans cette liste de pays, le second pays est l'Allemagne"... acceptable... ? ""Dans cette liste de pays, le tiers pays est l'Espagne"... inacceptable / ridicule / bizarre ? Je vous pose la question en tant que francophone...

Comment: *Tiers pays* est tout aussi inaceptable que *pays second*. A remarquer qu'avec etat: le *tiers etat* et l'*état second* ont des sens totalement différents de *état tiers* et *second état*.

Comment: @AlainD tiers-monde, tierce partie, Tiers-Etat...

Comment: Ce que je dis, c'est qu'on entend pas souvent : monde-tiers, partie-tiers (ou partie tièrce), état-tiers.

Answer (score 2):

Je comprends *tiers pays*, que je n'ai jamais rencontré hors la présente question, de la même façon que *Tiers-État* ou *tiers-monde*, c'est-à-dire une partie du pays, de l'état ou du monde qui n'est pas considérée comme principale, ni même comme seconde.

Je comprends *pays tiers* comme un pays extérieur aux pays signataires d'un accord bi- ou multilatéral.

Curieusement, je rapprocherais *tierce personne* d'*état tiers* et pas de *Tiers-État*.